# How to use objectAnimator in overridePendingTransition in android

Tags: java, android, animation, objectanimator

How to use objectAnimator in overridePendingTransition in android for 3D flip whenever activity switches in android

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an `ObjectAnimator` in conjunction with `overridePendingTransition()`, this is not possible.

You have to call `overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim)` with the ressource ids of existing animations defined in XML. There you can setup or tune the existing 3D flip from android.

Comment: How should that work programmatically? Activity transitions are done within the framework based on the supplied animation XML.

Comment: ah sorry, we are talking about Activities, i thought overridePendingTransition belongs to Fragments, sorry again

Comment: Done. Now i am used Fragment instead of Activity thanks for your comments